# Cesium convert lat lon to x and y

Tags: cesiumjs

I am looking to turn 2 lat/lon positions into an x and y distance of the canvas, then apply the distance formula to it.

Right now I have:

```
const leftPoint = new LatLon(center.lat, center.lon).destinationPoint(semiMajorAxis, 270);
                const rightPoint = new LatLon(center.lat, center.lon).destinationPoint(semiMajorAxis, 90);
                const leftXY = Cartographic.toCartesian(Cartographic.fromDegrees(leftPoint.lon, leftPoint.lat));
                const rightXY = Cartographic.toCartesian(Cartographic.fromDegrees(rightPoint.lon, rightPoint.lat));
                const diameter = distanceFormula(leftXY.x, leftXY.y, rightXY.x, rightXY.y);
```

But the result of diameter is 18,000, even though both points are on my screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cesium's `Cartographic.toCartesian` function converts a Cartographic (lon/lat/alt) type of coordinate to a full 3D Cartesian position.  Imagine X, Y, Z with zero being the center of the Earth itself, with the Earth's surface being approximately 6.3 million meters in any direction.

If you're looking for 2D canvas / screen coordinates, you must follow this call with another function, [`Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/SceneTransforms.html#.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates).  That function converts the 3D WGS84 (Cartesian3) Earth position into a 2D (Cartesian2) screen position. There's a demo of `wgs84ToWindowCoordinates` being used in the Sandcastle [Star Burst Example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Star%20Burst.html) around line 287.

Also it looks like you've rolled your own `LatLon` class, not specified above, that appears to have similar functions to Cesium's `Cartographic` class.  You might be able to make the code a little cleaner by using `Cartographic` directly instead of a homebrew class there.  Likewise you don't need to roll your own `distanceFormula` on the last line. Once you have 2D Cartesian2 window coordinates, call [`Cesium.Cartesian2.distance`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Cartesian2.html#.distance) to get the distance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your saying 'x and y distance of the canvas'.

Generally, for calculate distance between two point on CesiumJS follow below steps.

1.Define two points

```
//Define x,y coordinate and convert to radian
const longitudeRadian_1 = Cesium.Math.toRadians(longitudeDegree_1)
const latitudeRadian_1 = Cesium.Math.toRadians(latitudeDegree_1)
const longitudeRadian_2 = Cesium.Math.toRadians(longitudeDegree_2)
const latitudeRadian_2 = Cesium.Math.toRadians(latitudeDegree_2)

//Get cartographic from degrees
const Carto_Point_1 = new Cesium.Cartographic(longitudeRadian_1 , latitudeRadian_1 )
const Carto_Point_2 = new Cesium.Cartographic(longitudeRadian_2 , latitudeRadian_2)

//Get cartesian from cartographic
const Cartesian_Point_1 = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(Carto_Point_1)
const Cartesian_Point_2 = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(Carto_Point_2)
```

2.Calculate distance between two points

```
const distance = Cesium.Cartesian3.distance(Cartesian_Point_1, Cartesian_Point_2)

console.log(distance)
```

I hope this would help